# Counting the number of terms in a polynomial using Length command

Tags: polynomials

I have the following polynomial which depends on $n$:

```
poly = (Sum[(i - 1) y[i], {i, 1, n, 1}])^2  - Sum[(i - 1)^2 y[i]^2, {i, 2, n, 1}] // Expand;
```

The Mathematica `Length` command can be used to determine the length of `poly` for an arbitrarily chosen value of $n$.

For instance for $n=5$:

```
n=5; poly
```

> ```
> 4 y[2] y[3] + 6 y[2] y[4] + 12 y[3] y[4] + 8 y[2] y[5] + 16 y[3] y[5] + 24 y[4] y[5]
> ```

which yields for the length

```
Length[poly]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Similarly for $n=4$

```
n = 4; poly
```

> ```
> 4 y[2] y[3] + 6 y[2] y[4] + 12 y[3] y[4]
> ```

which yields for the length

```
Length[poly]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

But here comes the problem. For $n=3$, poly takes the following form

```
n = 3; poly
```

> ```
> 4 y[2] y[3]
> ```

which yields for the length

```
Length[poly]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

as opposed to 1. Since there is now only 1 term, it is counting each sub-term and taking that to be the length. What could be done to correct for this? I need it to only count the total number of terms for all values of $n$. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I was going to suggest manipulating heads and checking the length of arguments under the head `Plus`, but then I realized that `Length[CoefficientRules[poly]]` does the job nicely.

```
In[96]:= poly = 4 y[2] y[3]

Out[96]= 4 y[2] y[3]

In[97]:= CoefficientRules@poly

Out[97]= {{1, 1} -> 4}

In[98]:= Length@CoefficientRules@poly

Out[98]= 1
```

Alternatively you can do

```
Length[poly + Unique["x"]] - 1
```

which will ensure a head of `Plus` around the expression whose length is being checked.

Comment: +1 However, in general the second solution would need to include `Expand`: `Length[Expand[poly] + Unique["x"]] - 1`